# ng-repeat on object containing two other objects

Tags: javascript, angularjs, object

How can I get each data-record in an object containing to other objects like this:

```
data

    Object { abbData={...}, invoiceData={...}}

abbData

    Object { service="24", conn_fee="0", month_fee="249", more...}

invoiceData

    Object { invoice_fee="0", invoice_type="1", invoice_mail="khang64sv@hotmail.com", more...}
```

In exists two objects(abbData, invoiceData) in data. How can I get the records for abbData and invoiceData with ng-repeat?

Comment: how did you get `=` sign in Object.

Comment: @Mritunjay: What do you mean? The objects are returned from my backend.

Comment: That is not the way JSON format is supposed to be

Comment: Maybe show us a dump what is REALLY returned from your backend and not just some abstract description with buggy notation.

Comment: @mainguy: You can see the returned data in my question. It's copied directly from firebug.

Comment: Okay, then this is some of the strangest returns I've always seen from a backend. How do you think you will resolve the ellipses or "more..." What is the backend code that generates this output??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use:

```
ng-repeat="(prop, obj) in data"
```

with:

`prop` then containing the property name. (E.g.: `appData`, `invoiceData`)

and:

`obj` containing the actual object.

---

**html**:

```
<pre ng-repeat="(prop, obj) in data">
  <strong>{{ prop }}</strong>: {{ obj | json }}
</pre>
```

---

demo: http://jsbin.com/ximohage/1/

Comment: Hm, how do you mean? If I want to get all the records from the appData object in data, how can I extract it from there?

Comment: I have also tried like this: row in summary.invoiceData, summary is the scope variable that contains all the data from my backend.

Comment: @user500468 To be honest, if your problem is "how to access array/objects" in general, than you should take a step back and grab a good book on javascript. This issn't really an angular question.

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.item = {};
$scope.item.abbData={...};
$scope.item.invoiceData={...};
```